# Nooby Question/Concern about Python not working on Sublime 3

Tags: python, script-debugging

I've made a new python build system and inserted the following code into the build:

```
{
"cmd": ["C:\\Users\\Perez\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32", "-u", "$file"],
"file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
"selector": "source.python"}
```

I then named the build:

```
python37.sublime-build
```

so I went back to my original tab on stb3(which isnt the build system) to test it out. I used build with(having my new build system ready)
I used the very simple and iconic code:

```
print ("Hello, World!")
```

but it gives me this error:

```
[WinError 5] Access is denied
```

So, yeah. Can anyone help? 
(sidenote: im running STB3 on administrator)